# COALESCE function in SELECT Clause

Tags: mysql, t-sql, coalesce

Problem: is to find the last Non NULL value from the table based on id order, found here http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle

```
CREATE TABLE Score(`id` int, `col1` INT NULL);
INSERT INTO Score
    (`id`, `col1`)
VALUES
    (2, NULL),
    (3, 10),
    (5, -1),
    (7, NULL),
    (11, NULL),
    (13, -12),
    (17, NULL),
    (19, NULL),
    (23, 1759);
```

Desired Output:

```
id          col1        lastval
----------- ----------- -----------
2           NULL        NULL
3           10          10
5           -1          -1
7           NULL        -1
11          NULL        -1
13          -12         -12
17          NULL        -12
19          NULL        -12
23          1759        1759
```

My Code in SQLFiddle MySQL 5.6

```
SELECT s1.id, COALESCE(s2.col1)
FROM score s1 JOIN score s2
ON s1.id >= s2.id
GROUP BY s1.id
ORDER BY s1.id, s2.id DESC
```

COALESCE as I understand gives the first non NULL value encountered in a list. But It is giving `(null)` for all the columns. Can you point why `COALESCE` is not working? 
Also I realized removing the `COALESCE` should also answer the question as `GROUP BY` clause returns the first value in the `s2.col1` column. I might be wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COALESCE() returns the first non-null value *in its list of arguments.* There is no implicit behavior of applying the COALESCE() to the same expression over the set of grouped rows. It is not an aggregating function like SUM() or GROUP_CONCAT().

It makes no sense to use it with one argument as you're doing, because you've only given it one argument. So it's exactly the same as putting `s2.col1` in your query's select-list without putting it inside a COALESCE() call.

Then you're left with the default behavior of MySQL when referencing a non-grouped column in a GROUP BY function: MySQL chooses arbitrarily the value of `s2.col1` from some row in the group. In practice, this is the first row in the group read in index order, but you shouldn't depend on this.

So in your example, your join joins each row `s1` to all rows `s2` such that `s2.id` is earlier. Every group includes the first row in the table where `s2.id=2`. And that row has a NULL for col1.

I read through the SQL puzzle you're trying to solve. It's going to be particularly awkward in MySQL 5.x, because MySQL doesn't support windowing functions until version 8.0.2.

The solution in these cases usually involves using MySQL [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) that change value as your query iterates over the rows in the table. This can be quite tricky.

---

Here's how I would solve the problem in a portable way (with no MySQL user variables):

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.col1, s2.col1 as lastval
FROM Score AS s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Score AS s2 ON s2.id <= s1.id AND s2.col1 IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN Score AS s3 ON s3.id > s2.id AND s3.id <= s1.id AND s3.col1 IS NOT NULL
WHERE s3.id IS NULL
ORDER BY s1.id;
```

Here's how one could solve it using a MySQL user variable:

```
SELECT id, col1, @lastval := COALESCE(col1, @lastval) AS lastval
FROM (SELECT @lastval := NULL) AS _init 
CROSS JOIN Score
ORDER BY id;
```

I would avoid the query you posted in your comment below, because it uses a correlated subquery. Correlated subqueries are usually bad for performance.

Comment: I'm not much comfortable with user defined variables in SQL. But I found a solution. Can you confirm if this works
`SELECT s1.id, (SELECT s2.col1 FROM score s2 
               WHERE s2.id <= s1.id
                     AND s2.col1 IS NOT NULL
              ORDER BY s2.id DESC
              LIMIT 1) AS value
FROM score s1
ORDER BY s1.id`

Comment: Can you please explain your second query using MySQL user variable.

Comment: Instead of explaining how the @variables work in the 2nd query - consider upgrading MySQL or using a fiddle that supports a more recent MySQL e.g. dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @PaulMaxwell If that had been an option in 2016 when I answered this question, sure.

Comment: @BillKarwin oops - I had not noticed how old this was -  apologies

Comment: No problem, I did edit it today (in April 2023) to clarify that MySQL 8.0 now supports window functions, so perhaps it popped up in your feed. But I've posted nearly 9,000 answers on Stack Overflow, so I'm not going to revise all my old answers when MySQL develops new features. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you tyr to do and also i am not sure is it going to work on mysql but this one works on tsql. I hope it helps

```
    SELECT s1.id, COALESCE(min(s2.col1),0) FROM score s1 
    JOIN score s2 ON s1.id >= s2.id GROUP BY s1.id
    ORDER BY s1.id, min(s2.col1) DESC
```

Comment: See the link in [Question](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle). Can you explain why you did this `COALESCE(min(s2.col1),0)`  and how does this work?

Comment: your output is not what was desired. I've edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: The way ı use coalesce()  for handle the result of an operation not the parameter, For example if I have  sum(a)/sum(b) i can handle null if with coalesce().  I am checking you question again and try to understand what you want to do